# sonar build stability plugin gives 403 forbidden error for sonarqube version 3.1.1

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

My configuration is SonarQube 3.1.1, Build Stability plugin 1.2, Jenkins 1.467

I have configured the settings for the build stability plugin at the project level as mentioned at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Stability+Plugin

Console output for this analysis has the following error for this plugin :

```
> [INFO] [05:17:18.108] CI URL: Jenkins:http://<host>/job/<job-name>/
> 
> [ERROR] [05:17:18.702] Received 403 when trying to access
> http://<host>/job/<job-name>//lastBuild/api/xml/
> org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Received 403 when trying to access
> http://<host>/job/<job-name>//lastBuild/api/xml/  at
> org.sonar.plugins.buildstability.ci.CiConnector.execute(CiConnector.java:132)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.sonar.plugins.buildstability.ci.CiConnector.executeGet(CiConnector.java:120)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.sonar.plugins.buildstability.ci.CiConnector.getLastBuild(CiConnector.java:68)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.sonar.plugins.buildstability.ci.CiConnector.getBuildsSince(CiConnector.java:106)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.sonar.plugins.buildstability.BuildStabilitySensor.analyse(BuildStabilitySensor.java:105)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:64)
> [sonar-batch-3.1.1.jar:na]    at
> org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:93)
> [sonar-batch-3.1.1.jar:na]    at
> org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectModule.doStart(ProjectModule.java:139)
> [sonar-batch-3.1.1.jar:na]    at
> org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
> [sonar-batch-3.1.1.jar:na]    at
> org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:115)
> [sonar-batch-3.1.1.jar:na]    at
> org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.doStart(BatchModule.java:105)
> [sonar-batch-3.1.1.jar:na]    at
> org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
> [sonar-batch-3.1.1.jar:na]    at
> org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.java:111)
> [sonar-batch-3.1.1.jar:na]    at
> org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
> [sonar-batch-3.1.1.jar:na]    at
> org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:73)
> [sonar-batch-3.1.1.jar:na]    at
> org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:60)
> [sonar-batch-3.1.1.jar:na]    at
> org.sonar.maven3.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:142)
> [sonar-maven3-plugin-3.1.1.jar:na]    at
> org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:104)
> [sonar-maven-plugin-2.2.jar:na]   at
> org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:67)
> [sonar-maven-plugin-2.2.jar:na]   at
> org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:109)
> [sonar-maven-plugin-2.2.jar:na]   at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
> [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
> [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
> [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
> [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
> [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
> [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
> [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
> [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
> [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
> [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
> [maven-embedder-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
> [maven-embedder-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
> [maven-embedder-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> ~[na:1.6.0_33]    at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
> ~[na:1.6.0_33]    at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
> ~[na:1.6.0_33]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
> ~[na:1.6.0_33]    at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
> [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]   at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
> [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]   at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
> [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]   at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
> [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na] [INFO] [05:17:18.704] Sensor
> org.sonar.plugins.buildstability.BuildStabilitySensor@1188d9a3 done:
> 597 ms
```

Link : `http://<host>/job/<job-name>//lastBuild/api/xml/` is accessible through web browser and is a correct url.

I even provided  `-Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=admin` in the sonar configuration of the build, but still the same error appears.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure <host> and <job-name> are replaced by their real values ? Can you use a tool like curl to access that url from the box where Sonar is running? Do you get the url or a 403?

Comment: Have you imported the SSL certificate of your Jenkins instance in your Java keystore? If no, then this could be the reason why it is failing.

Comment: apology..but the url in the above post is http in place of https

Comment: OK, and have you set the credentials (in the settings page of "Buld Stability") required to access your Jenkins instance if it is secured?

Comment: I set the credentials for accessing the CI server in the settings page of the build stability plugin, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the Sonar authentication fails depending on the security you use on your Jenkins server. I believe it's possible to set `sonar.build-stability.use_jsecuritycheck=true` if Jenkins security realm is delegated to the servlet container (tomcat server.xml).

In my own case, I had no choice but using the standard security (Jenkins database), and I had trouble when I configured SonarQube Build Stability, even when I was sure to use the right URL with matching credentials.

Then I tried another Build Stability configuration, removing user and password, and including the credentials in URL :
`Jenkins:http(s)://<user>:<pass>@<hostname>/job/<jobname>`
...fail...

Finally I tried another url pattern, using the given api token (user configuration in jenkins) instead of password :
`Jenkins:http(s)://<user>:<api-token>@<hostname>/job/<jobname>`

This last try was a success. I even removed my SonarQube user from the global security list in Jenkins and just gave it read/discover right at project level, and it still worked.

It doesn't fill my deep desire to fill the "username/password" in the Sonar config (I WANT to use these fields...) anyway it's more secured than granting anonymous access. But still, there is a security token in the URL so the security is not as good as I want.

Hope it helped.

- Edit

1) With the Jenkins Role Strategy plugin, the user needs the overall read permission in addition to the project read permission.

2) When Jenkins delegates authentication to servlet container and you set `sonar.build-stability.user_jsecuritycheck=true` in Sonar, you will probably get an error with Build Stability v1.2. A wrong url is generated when it tries to authenticate on Jenkins (one / is missing in the url, generating something like `http://<my_host>/jenkinsloginEntry` instead of `http://<my_host>/jenkins/loginEntry`). Should be fixed in v1.3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. If it can help, here a workaround: in Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security, grant Anonymous user to read both Overall and Job.

Comment: i tried this workaround and it did generate the build stability graph on the sonar dashboard. But the console output of this build shows the following message : 
[INFO] [06:57:33.643] CI URL: Jenkins:http://<hostname>/job/<jobname>
[WARN] [06:57:35.755] Received 404 when trying to access http://<hostname>/job/<jobname>/408/api/xml/
[WARN] [06:57:35.758] Received 404 when trying to access http://<hostname>/job/<jobname>/407/api/xml/
[WARN] [06:57:35.765] Received 404 when trying to access http://<hostname>/job/<jobname>/406/api/xml/
and so on.

Comment: ALso  for one of the jobs,on the build stability graph it states 21 builds, 1 failed but the graph has 20 bars all green indicating successful builds but no bar in red indicating failure.

Is this right or something is a miss?

Comment: And for the graph, also in my case, the last build is not displayed.

Comment: thanks that link helped. Any idea why the failure of one build is not reflecting in the graph? In the console it says Retrieved 21 builds. but the graph has 20 green coloured bars whereas one build failed from those 21 builds.

Comment: Not sure... Try to make successful and failed build. The failed build may not appear because it's the last one you did.

Comment: So can we say confirm that the anonymous access issue is a bug in this build stability plugin version 1.2 ?

Comment: Yeah, or minor issue. You could talk about it on this [forum](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/SonarQube-Developers-f4523654.html).